# I have 10 tables in schema icmdb2admin each table has one column named pdfname i need to update the values in the pdfname column with L1.pdfname.V1

Tags: postgresql, update

```
DECLARE
    i record;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN SELECT 'icmdb2admin.' || tablename as tbp  
             FROM pg_tables 
             WHERE schemaname = 'icmdb2admin' 
               and tablename <> 'department_master' 
               and tablename <> 'year'
               and tablename <> 'user_login' 
               and tablename <> 'filetype'  
               -- and other conditions, if needed
    LOOP 
         EXECUTE  UPDATE 'i.tbp' SET "pdfname" = 'L1.'|| pdfname || '.V1'; 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the list of tables that have one column name `pdfname` by using the `information_schema.columns` view. It makes for clearer code.

Let's assume this is your (very simplified) scenario:

```
CREATE SCHEMA icmdb2admin ;
SET search_path = icmdb2admin ;

CREATE TABLE t1 (pdfname varchar(100)) ;
CREATE TABLE t2 (pdfname varchar(100)) ;
CREATE TABLE "with an awful name"(pdfname varchar(100)) ;
CREATE TABLE "no no"(i integer);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('hi'),('you');
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES('ha'),('you');
INSERT INTO "with an awful name" VALUES('he'),('you');
```

You get the list of the tables you want by means of the following query:

```
SELECT
    table_name
FROM
    information_schema.columns c 
WHERE
    column_name = 'pdfname' 
    AND table_schema = 'icmdb2admin' ;
```

That will return

```
| table_name         |
| :----------------- |
| t2                 |
| with an awful name |
| t1                 |
```

You then will use this information to [`EXECUTE` dynamic command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) using PLPGSQL with any of the table names retrieved from the previous query:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('
        UPDATE
             "icmdb2admin"."%s"
        SET
             pdfname = ''L1.''|| pdfname || ''.V1''
        ', 
        't1') ;
END;
$$
```

That will change (only) table `t1`.

NOTE: The `format` function allows for better readability, and adequate type formatting and prevention of SQL injection than plain concatenation.

At this point, to update *all* the concerned tables, you would use a `loop`, in a fashion similar to the one you already devised:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    tbl character varying ; -- Not the whole record, only what you're interested in
BEGIN
    for tbl IN
        SELECT
            table_name
        FROM
            information_schema.columns 
        WHERE
            column_name = 'pdfname' 
            AND table_schema = 'icmdb2admin'
            /* AND whatever else you need */
    loop
        -- raise notice '%', tbl ;  -- debugging tool
        EXECUTE format('
            UPDATE
                 "icmdb2admin"."%s"
            SET
                 pdfname = ''L1.''|| pdfname || ''.V1''
            ', 
            tbl) ;
    end loop ;
END ;
$$
```

And your tables will now have:

```
SELECT * FROM t1;
```

```
| pdfname         |
| :-------------- |
| L1.L1.hi.V1.V1  |
| L1.L1.you.V1.V1 |
```

```
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

```
| pdfname   |
| :-------- |
| L1.ha.V1  |
| L1.you.V1 |
```

```
SELECT * FROM "with an awful name";
```

```
| pdfname   |
| :-------- |
| L1.he.V1  |
| L1.you.V1 |
```

You can check a step-by-step example (with some limitations due to restrictions on dbfidle at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3bd1e39c6ea412b0c4475facd7ed6aef)*

---

NOTE: table `t1` has been update twice in this example, on purpose. To avoid this possible problems, you could probably rewrite the UPDATEs adding a `WHERE NOT pdfname LIKE 'L1.%.V1'` to prevent double updates during testing.

---

References in PostgreSQL documentation:

- [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)
- [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)
- [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/infoschema-columns.html)